# Uncaught TypeError: Object function (){return i.apply(this,arguments)} has no method 'on'

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

For some reasons, I keep on getting this error, (See attached screenshot). I've tried adding a `_.bindAll(this);` and even tried upgrading my code to have the latest version of backbonejs. Still no luck.

Can someone help me on this?

[image]

```
var app = app || {};

(function ($) {
'use strict';

app.EmployeeView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#container',
    model: app.Employee,
    events: {
        'click #save' : 'saveEntry'
    },
    initialize: function(){
        console.log('Inside Initialization!');
        this.$empName = this.$('#txtEmpName');
        this.$department = this.$('#txtDepartment');
        this.$designation = this.$('#txtDesignation');
        this.listenTo(app.employees, 'add', this.addEmployee);
        app.employees.fetch();
        console.log('End of Initialization!');
        //this.render();
    },
    render: function () {
        console.log('Inside Render!!');
        console.log(this.model);
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        console.log('Inside End of Render!!');
        return this;
    },
    newAttributes: function(){
        return{
            empName: this.$empName.val(),
            department: this.$department.val(),
            designation: this.$designation.val()
        };
    },

    saveEntry: function(){
        console.log('Inside SaveEntry!');
        //console.log(this.newAttributes());
        console.log('this.model');
        console.log(app.Employee);
        //app.employees.create(this.newAttributes());
        app.Employee.set(this.newAttributes());
        app.employees.add(app.Employee);
        console.log('After SaveEntry!');
    },
    addEmployee: function (todo) {
        var view = new app.EmployeeItemView({ model: app.Employee });
        $('#empInfo').append(view.render().el);
    }
})
})(jQuery);
```

Code for "collections/employees.js"

```
var app = app || {};
(function (){
    console.log('Inside collection');
    var Employees = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: app.Employee,
        localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage('employee-db')
    });
    app.employees = new Employees();
})();
```

Code for "model/employee.js"

```
var app = app || {};
(function(){
    'use strict';

    app.Employee = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            empName: '',
            department: '',
            designation: '' 
        }
    });
})();
```

Comment: Please, add your code. However, I can almost for sure tell you that you have not created object properly and call `on` on a constructor not on an object.

Comment: However, If I move the statement "this.listenTo(app.employees, 'add', this.addEmployee);" after "app.employees.fetch();" the error disappears where it shows another error stating, "Uncaught TypeError: Object function (){return i.apply(this,arguments)} has no method 'toJSON'"

Comment: Could you also add code where you initialize `app.employees` and `app.Employee`.

Comment: Thanks!. I've added the code now. Pls check

Comment: Thanks @minitech for the edit! Still a novice to StackOverflow. My apologies.

Comment: @ChrisCamaratta I've just checked that. The inclusion of collection/employees.js comes first before EmpolyeeView inclusion. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.model.toJSON()` won't work since `this.model` is the `app.Employee` constructor. Actually I don't see any meaning in your `EmployeeView.render` method. If it is aggregate view why you have model on it? Otherwise what is the second view class `EmployeeItemView`? If you're following ToDo MVC example you can see that there is no model in `AppView`, that is why I conclude you need not model in your `EmployeeView`. And `render` method you provided seems to belong to `EmployeeItemView`.

Secondly, you call `app.Employee.set` which is also a call on a constructor not on an object. I think you meant

```
saveEntry: function(){
    console.log('Inside SaveEntry!');
    app.employees.create(this.newAttributes());
    console.log('After SaveEntry!');
},
```

If you want to pass a model to `app.EmployeeItemView` you should use callback argument.

```
addEmployee: function (employee) {
    var view = new app.EmployeeItemView({ model: employee });
    $('#empInfo').append(view.render().el);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You're saying this in your view:

```
model: app.Employee
```

`app.Employee` looks like a model "class" rather than a model instance. Your view wants a model instance in its `model` property. Normally you'd say something like this:

```
var employee = new app.Employee(...);
var view = new app.EmployeeView({ model: employee });
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer!. However I'm just cloning the TodoMVC example in my Employee application. I'm afraid, I'm not finding these kind of instantiation there. (Please correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: Typically the model is passed in when you initialize your view: `new EmployeeView({ model: employeeInstance })`

Comment: There are errors in your cloning process, TodoMVC would be badly broken if it did things like that. Can you link to the part of TodoMVC that you're cloning for this?